# Laravel 8 Undefined variable: comments

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I am trying to build a commenting system where users are able to leave comments behind on posts.

I can save and display the post and on a page i display all post I have a form where users can leave comments behind. I am able to save the comments in the database but when I try to show the comments I get this error Undefined variable: comments (View: /var/www/resources/views/projects/comment.blade.php).

My files: Comment Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Comment extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'post_id', 'parent_id', 'description'];

    /**
     * Write Your Code..
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Write Your Code..
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function replies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Post Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [ 'titre',
    'description',
    'image',
    'tag',
    'video',
    'status',
    'user_id'];

    /**
     * Write Your Code..
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->whereNull('parent_id');
    }
}
```

My CommentController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Comment;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write Your Code..
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $request->validate([
            'body'=>'required',
        ]);

        $input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;

        Comment::create($input);

        return back();
    }
}
```

post display controller

```
    public function post_display()
    {
        if(Auth::id()){
          
          $userid=Auth::user()->id;
          $profile=user::find($userid);
          $post=post::where('user_id',$userid)->get();
  
        return view('user.post_display',compact('post','profile'));
        }
        else{
          return redirect()->back();
        }
      }
```

My post display view

```
@include('user.head')

@include('user.create_post')


<section class="ftco-section">
            <div class="container"  align="center" >
                       @foreach($post as $posts)
        @if(session()->has('message2'))
         <div class="alert alert-success">
             
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
                 x
             </button>
             
             {{session()->get('message2')}}

         </div>
        @endif
       <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-6 middle-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 grid-margin">
                    <div class="card rounded">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <img class="img-xs rounded-circle" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png" alt="">
                                    <div class="ml-2">
                                        <p>{{$profile->username}}</p>
                                        <p class="tx-11 text-muted">{{$posts->created_at}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                @include('user.update_post')
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                              <h5> {{$posts->tag}}
                              </h5>
                            <h4 class="mb-3 tx-14"> {{$posts->status}}</h4>
                            <p class="mb-3 tx-14"> {{$posts->description}}</p>

                            <img class="img-fluid" src="postimage/{{$posts->image}}" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="d-flex post-actions">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="d-flex align-items-center text-muted mr-4">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-heart icon-md">
                                        <path d="M20.84 4.61a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 0L12 5.67l-1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0-7.78 7.78l1.06 1.06L12 21.23l7.78-7.78 1.06-1.06a5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0-7.78z"></path>
                                    </svg>
                                    <p class="d-none d-md-block ml-2">Like</p>
                                </a>
                                <h4>Display Comments</h4>
  
                    <hr />
                    @include('user.comment', ['comments' => $posts->comments, 'post_id' => $posts->id])
   
                    <h4>Add comment</h4>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="description"></textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $posts->id }}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Comment" />
                        </div>
                    </form>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
          </section>

 @include('user.footer')
  <!-- loader -->
  <div id="ftco-loader" class="show fullscreen"><svg class="circular" width="48px" height="48px"><circle class="path-bg" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="#eeeeee"/><circle class="path" cx="24" cy="24" r="22" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke="#F96D00"/></svg></div>    
    @include('user.script')  
  </body>
```

my comment dispaly view

```
@foreach($comments as $comments)
    <div class="display-comment" @if($comments->parent_id != null) style="margin-left:40px;" @endif>
        <strong>{{ $comments->user->name }}</strong>
        <p>{{ $comments->body }}</p>
        <a href="" id="reply"></a>
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('comments.store') }}">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="body" class="form-control" />
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ $post_id }}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comments->id }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Reply" />
            </div>
            <hr />
        </form>
        @include('user.comment', ['comments' => $comments->replies])
    </div>
@endforeach
```

My comment routes:

```
Route::post('comment',[CommentController::class,'comment'])->name('comments.store');
```

whene i try to create a new laravel project and put nothing other then post and comment it work.so i don't know where is the error.

Comment: I believe the same variable at the `foreach` is problematic: `@foreach($comments as $comments)`? ... in the posts blade you have `@foreach($post as $posts)`. Likely a matter of preference, but I like to have those the other way around, where the collection (as a plural) is first before `as`, and a singular variable after the `as`  that is used within the loop. As an example: `foreach ($comments as $comment)` and the same for posts `foreach ($posts as $post)`

Comment: thank you so much for your help, it's finally working.

Comment: @PaulT. you should propose a solution so that @Nouhaila Khaouti can vote as `answered`